# PL/SQL Best way of Checking Table then Pulling the Data given that check Passes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Good Afternoon,

I am using both of these examples when needing to first check if the count of a query is = 1, then if =1, pull the data from that same table  in PL/SQL block

### Approach 1

```
DECLARE
v_count number;
v_name varchar2(255);
BEGIN

select count(*) into v_count from THE_USERS where USERID = :IN_ID;

if v_count <> 1 then
raise error;
end if;

select first_name || ' ' || last_name fullname into v_name from THE_USERS where USERID = :IN_ID;

....Other Stuff

END;
```

### Approach 2

```
DECLARE
v_count number;
v_name varchar2(255);
BEGIN

select count(*), max(first_name || ' ' || last_name) fullname into v_count, v_name from THE_USERS where USERID = :IN_ID;

if v_count <> 1 then

raise error;
end if;
 
....Other Stuff

END;
```

So I started off with Approach 1, but #2 looks seems to be better just so there is less code, but Im not sure if that would cause a performance hit for the max().   I also rarely expect that error to be thrown compared to the one result.

[Similar Example, but not same end goal as me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140868/proper-way-of-checking-if-row-exists-in-table-in-pl-sql-block.)

Let me know if anymore information would be useful.

Comment: I wouldn't expect `MAX` to have much performance impact since it appears you're expecting only one matching row anyway, but I guess the safest thing to do would be to use `ANY_VALUE` instead so Oracle can easily optimize. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/any_value.html#GUID-A3C47D5E-B145-40B2-93D2-CA3BA65C2D81

Comment: Cool I didnt know that was something available!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to query the table twice, just query the table for the data you want and catch the exceptions if there are too many or too few rows:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_name varchar2(255);
BEGIN
  select first_name || ' ' || last_name
  into   v_name
  from   THE_USERS
  where  USERID = :IN_ID;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    -- Handle zero rows
    NULL;
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    -- Handle more than 1 row.
    NULL;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YQ8vR3pC)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the best approach! I may stick with the any_value keyword inplace of max to not have to rewrite all my cowerkers code . But will start using this on newer things