# PLSQL : If variable IN subquery

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possibile in PL/SQL function something like

```
IF xVar IN (SELECT yVar
            FROM....)
THEN...
```

this?
Thank you

Comment: See a couple ways here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217600/if-exists-condition-not-working-with-plsql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will probably have to so something like

```
select count(*) 
into foo 
from blah
where yVar = xVar

if foo > 0 then ...
```

Or you could make a function that returns boolean if this is something you'd use often

Answer (score 0):

You can use FOR-IN with your implicit cursor. I know only IF-THEN-ELSE operator with IF expression.