# "If not exist"-condition in a case in SQL-procedure from Oracle-Database

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I´m kind of new to SQL-Procedures, but I´ve written a procedure which adds a line to my datatable. This works pretty fine, but when i run trough the procedure twice i want to avoid the line being added again into the datatable based on an Oracle-Database. So my question is, how to set the "if already exists"-condition within the case command.

My code looks like that:

```
...
case number

when 5 then 

/* if not exists` <<--- i need something to avoid doubled entrys */

  pi_event_line_add(5,'xxx' ....);


end case;
end procedure;
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: i hope this helps..

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13217600/266304)?

Comment: add a unique constraint on the target table. This is the best solution.

Comment: @AlexPoole i´ll try this out, that looks like a good solution.

Comment: @MattisSeehaus - [look at this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3841441/266304); leans towards catching the exception (as Florin suggests).

Comment: Thank you @AlexPoole i made it a little different, but it works perfectly! I´ll share my answer soon. Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Sharing what you did probably isn't going to add much to the general store of knowledge, if it's based on one of those existing answers. This can be closed as a duplicate of whichever old question you used.

Comment: hm yes you´re right. i just used two different case-statements now and combined them into another referring to [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217600/if-exists-condition-not-working-with-plsql)

Answer (score 0):

One solution, is to interrogate your table first then decide to insert.  Like:

```
declare cnt number;

begin
select count(*) into cnt from your_table where id = 5;

if cnt = 0 then
   pi_event_line_add(5,'xxx'...);
end if;
```

Also, you probably want to add a unique constraint on the column that stores "5" if it truly should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` statement in `pi_event_line_add` instead of an `INSERT`. In the `MERGE` only implement the `WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT` portion of the statement.

Best of luck.